# Como documentar codigo en Dart

Tags: dart

Al investigar sobre la documentación de código  en el lenguaje Dart, no me arroja mucha inf, entonces la pregunta es si se documenta igual o algo similar al lenguaje Java, por ejemplo;

```
/**

* Esta clase define objetos que contienen tantos enteros aleatorios entre 0 y 1000 como se le definen al crear un objeto

* @author: Ma

* @version: 22/09/2016/A

* @see <a href = "http://www.apren.com" /> aprend.com – Didáctica en programación </a>

*/
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation

Comment: @BetaM muchas gracias ,inf muy útil

Comment: @BetaM Debe estar en ingles?

Comment: con el doble // en visual Studio code creo que hay un short cut que es ctrl+k+c o se pueden configurar y hacen la vida más sencilla :)